# Dependent dropdown list passing value in to another form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cascadingdropdown

i am newbie in php ..i want to create dependent dropdown list from mysql database and want to pass those selected field in to another form .How to do that ?please give me an example with brief description.Every help is much appreciated ...

Comment: SO is not here to code for you, do some research and have a go yourself, then SO can help with any problems you experience.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I am not providing you deatils code. (This question example are all around the web, if you little google it you will get it). Althoug, if you do not know how you should implement those. I just going you give idea:

I suggest you look into AJAX - which will allow you to update sections of your form based upon changes to other sections.

AJAX calls are in javaScript -> which calls a .php file -> with the appropriate code (like the value from a changed dropdown selection).

Comment: If you like video turoail can check here-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dn8PGBi5PQ  (There are many search youtube)  Complete tutorial -. https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/    learn, then you will know how to implement

Comment: i already write a code for jquery where i can get the selected value from combobox but unable to pass those value from one form to another ..here is my code  
<script>



function showMsg()
{




var conceptName = $('#country-list').find(":selected").text();


document.write (conceptName); 


 $("#msgC").html($("#country-list option:selected").text());
 $("#msgS").html($("#state-list option:selected").text());
    $("#msgN").html($("#state-name option:selected").text());
 return false;
}
</script>